# Sequelize Error - belongsTo called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model

Tags: sql, node.js, database, express, sequelize.js

I'm encountering an issue with Sequelize when trying to define a belongsTo association between the Comment and User models. The error message I'm receiving is:
`comment.belongsTo called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model at Object.<anonymous> (C:\code\project\Main\models\Comment.js:45:9)`

Here's the relevant code:

User Model (user.js):

```
const { Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../config/connection');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const Post = require('./Post');
const Comment = require('./Comment');

class User extends Model {
  checkPassword(loginPw) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(loginPw, this.password);
  }
}

User.init(
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    username: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: true,
      validate: {
        isEmail: true,
      },
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      validate: {
        len: [4],
      },
    },
  },
  {
    hooks: {
      async beforeCreate(newUserData) {
        newUserData.password = await bcrypt.hash(newUserData.password, 10);
        return newUserData;
      },
      async beforeUpdate(updatedUserData) {
        updatedUserData.password = await bcrypt.hash(
          updatedUserData.password,
          10,
        );
        return updatedUserData;
      },
    },
    sequelize,
    timestamps: false,
    freezeTableName: true,
    underscored: true,
    modelName: 'user',
  },
);

User.hasMany(Post, {
  foreignKey: 'user_id',
  onDelete: 'CASCADE',
});

User.hasMany(Comment, {
  foreignKey: 'user_id',
  onDelete: 'CASCADE',
});

module.exports = User;
```

Comment Model (comment.js):

```
const { Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../config/connection');
const User = require('./User');
const Post = require('./Post');

class Comment extends Model {}

Comment.init(
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    comment_text: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    user_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: User,
        key: 'id',
      },
    },
    post_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
        model: Post,
        key: 'id',
      },
    },
  },
  {
    sequelize,
    freezeTableName: true,
    underscored: true,
    modelName: 'comment',
  },
);

Comment.belongsTo(User, {
  foreignKey: 'user_id',
  onDelete: 'CASCADE'
});

module.exports = Comment;
```

Post Model (post.js):

```
const { Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../config/connection');
const User = require('./User');
const Comment = require('./Comment');

class Post extends Model {}

Post.init(
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    title: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      validate: {
        len: [1],
      },
    },
    content: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      validate: {
        len: [1],
      },
    },
    user_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      references: {
        model: User,
        key: 'id',
      },
    },
  },
  {
    sequelize,
    freezeTableName: true,
    underscored: true,
    modelName: 'post',
  },
);

Post.hasMany(Comment, {
  foreignKey: 'post_id',
  onDelete: 'CASCADE'
});

module.exports = Post;
```

And finally my Index ('index.js'):

```
const User = require('./User');
const Post = require('./Post');
const Comment = require('./Comment');

User.hasMany(Post, {
  foreignKey: 'user_id',
  onDelete: 'CASCADE',
});

User.hasMany(Comment, {
  foreignKey: 'user_id',
});

Post.belongsTo(User, {
  foreignKey: 'user_id',
});

Post.hasMany(Comment, {
  foreignKey: 'post_id',
  onDelete: 'CASCADE',
});

Comment.belongsTo(User, {
  foreignKey: 'user_id',
});

Comment.belongsTo(Post, {
  foreignKey: 'post_id',
});

module.exports = { User, Post, Comment };
```

I've checked for circular dependencies and verified the import statements. If you have any suggestions or insights into what might be causing this issue, I would greatly appreciate your help.

Thanks!

Comment: Just move all association definitions to index,js and remove them from model modules